# Separate Key/Value pairs after parsing for styling

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, key-value

I have this code parsing a large JSON object into it's key/value pairs

```
var origObject = {"id":3,"code":"\nfrom ipwhois import IPWhois\nimport json\nobj = IPWhois('104.24.114.36')\nresults = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)\nprint(json.dumps(results))\n","state":"available","output":{"status":"ok","execution_count":3,"data":{"text/plain":"{\"raw\": null, \"entities\": [\"CLOUD14\", \"ABUSE2916-ARIN\", \"ADMIN2521-ARIN\", \"NOC11962-ARIN\"], \"asn_registry\": \"arin\", \"network\": {\"status\": null, \"handle\": \"NET-104-16-0-0-1\", \"name\": \"CLOUDFLARENET\", \"links\": [\"https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/104.16.0.0\", \"https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1\"], \"raw\": null, \"country\": null, \"ip_version\": \"v4\", \"start_address\": \"104.16.0.0\", \"notices\": [{\"description\": \"By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use\", \"links\": [\"https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html\"], \"title\": \"Terms of Service\"}], \"end_address\": \"104.31.255.255\", \"remarks\": [], \"parent_handle\": \"NET-104-0-0-0-0\", \"cidr\": \"104.16.0.0/12\", \"type\": null, \"events\": [{\"action\": \"last changed\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-17T18:08:30-05:00\", \"actor\": null}, {\"action\": \"registration\", \"timestamp\": \"2014-03-28T10:30:55-04:00\", \"actor\": null}]}, \"objects\": {\"CLOUD14\": {\"status\": null, \"roles\": [\"registrant\"], \"handle\": \"CLOUD14\", \"entities\": [\"ABUSE2916-ARIN\", \"ADMIN2521-ARIN\", \"NOC11962-ARIN\"], \"links\": [\"https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CLOUD14\", \"https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14\"], \"raw\": null, \"notices\": null, \"contact\": {\"kind\": \"org\", \"name\": \"Cloudflare, Inc.\", \"title\": null, \"phone\": null, \"role\": null, \"address\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"101 Townsend Street\\nSan Francisco\\nCA\\n94107\\nUnited States\"}], \"email\": null}, \"events_actor\": null, \"remarks\": [], \"events\": [{\"action\": \"last changed\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-17T18:19:16-05:00\", \"actor\": null}, {\"action\": \"registration\", \"timestamp\": \"2010-07-09T13:10:42-04:00\", \"actor\": null}]}, \"ADMIN2521-ARIN\": {\"status\": [\"validated\"], \"roles\": [\"technical\"], \"handle\": \"ADMIN2521-ARIN\", \"entities\": null, \"links\": [\"https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADMIN2521-ARIN\", \"https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN\"], \"raw\": null, \"notices\": null, \"contact\": {\"kind\": \"group\", \"name\": \"Admin\", \"title\": null, \"phone\": [{\"type\": [\"work\", \"voice\"], \"value\": \"+1-650-319-8930\"}], \"role\": null, \"address\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"101 Townsend Street\\nSan Francisco\\nCA\\n94107\\nUnited States\"}], \"email\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"rir@cloudflare.com\"}]}, \"events_actor\": null, \"remarks\": [], \"events\": [{\"action\": \"last changed\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-10-05T15:42:30-04:00\", \"actor\": null}, {\"action\": \"registration\", \"timestamp\": \"2011-04-19T15:11:36-04:00\", \"actor\": null}]}, \"ABUSE2916-ARIN\": {\"status\": [\"validated\"], \"roles\": [\"abuse\"], \"handle\": \"ABUSE2916-ARIN\", \"entities\": null, \"links\": [\"https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE2916-ARIN\", \"https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN\"], \"raw\": null, \"notices\": null, \"contact\": {\"kind\": \"group\", \"name\": \"Abuse\", \"title\": null, \"phone\": [{\"type\": [\"work\", \"voice\"], \"value\": \"+1-650-319-8930\"}], \"role\": null, \"address\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"101 Townsend Street\\nSan Francisco\\nCA\\n94107\\nUnited States\"}], \"email\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"abuse@cloudflare.com\"}]}, \"events_actor\": null, \"remarks\": [], \"events\": [{\"action\": \"last changed\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-17T18:11:38-05:00\", \"actor\": null}, {\"action\": \"registration\", \"timestamp\": \"2011-02-14T19:00:47-05:00\", \"actor\": null}]}, \"NOC11962-ARIN\": {\"status\": [\"validated\"], \"roles\": [\"noc\"], \"handle\": \"NOC11962-ARIN\", \"entities\": null, \"links\": [\"https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC11962-ARIN\", \"https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN\"], \"raw\": null, \"notices\": null, \"contact\": {\"kind\": \"group\", \"name\": \"NOC\", \"title\": null, \"phone\": [{\"type\": [\"work\", \"voice\"], \"value\": \"+1-650-319-8930\"}], \"role\": null, \"address\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"101 Townsend Street\\nSan Francisco\\nCA\\n94107\\nUnited States\"}], \"email\": [{\"type\": null, \"value\": \"noc@cloudflare.com\"}]}, \"events_actor\": null, \"remarks\": [], \"events\": [{\"action\": \"last changed\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-02-17T18:15:44-05:00\", \"actor\": null}, {\"action\": \"registration\", \"timestamp\": \"2011-04-19T15:25:31-04:00\", \"actor\": null}]}}, \"asn_country_code\": \"US\", \"asn_date\": \"2014-03-28\", \"asn_cidr\": \"104.24.112.0/20\", \"nir\": null, \"query\": \"104.24.114.36\", \"asn\": \"13335\"}"}},"progress":1.0}; 
    var myTarget = origObject.output.data['text/plain'];
    var obj = JSON.parse(myTarget);
    var results = [];

    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        results.push(key + " : " + obj[key] );
      }
    }
```

and displaying in the return() like this

```
{results.map((value) => <p> {value} </p>)}
```

I need to be able to separate the key values so I can style them/possibly put them in a formatted table, etc... Right now I am just getting one dump of the results push.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Map( ) instead of an Array?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set

Short tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAJ82Ma33kM

It will let you keep the key and the value plus make sure that the keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` iterates over arrays. You have an object.

What you can do is get an array of your object's keys and iterate over them while passing each key to your object.

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => <p>{ obj[key] }</p>)
```

Comment: so you're saying use results.keys(obj).map(key => <p>{ obj[key] }</p>) in the html? I'm get a TypeError: results.keys(...).map is not a function when I try to compile.

Comment: No don't use results. Use the code that I posted. `obj` is the parsed object in your code. Get rid of the `for...in` loop and get rid of `results`

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work either. I keep getting this error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {status, handle, name, links, raw, country, ip_version, start_address, notices, end_address, remarks, parent_handle, cidr, type, events}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Comment: @RobiminusMaximus No need to use the F-word here.

Comment: @chade thats not helping, I'm allowed to express frustration but thanks

Comment: @Rob that probably has to do with how your object is setup. Looks like you have nested objects

Comment: Ok I see, well thanks for the help. I'll take a look at the json structure

Comment: @Rob stringify the output. I think that should work. `<p>{JSON.stringify(obj[key])}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo**

```js
var obj = {"raw":null,"entities":["CLOUD14","ABUSE2916-ARIN","ADMIN2521-ARIN","NOC11962-ARIN"],"asn_registry":"arin","network":{"status":null,"handle":"NET-104-16-0-0-1","name":"CLOUDFLARENET","links":["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/104.16.0.0","https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1"],"raw":null,"country":null,"ip_version":"v4","start_address":"104.16.0.0","notices":[{"description":"By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use","links":["https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"],"title":"Terms of Service"}],"end_address":"104.31.255.255","remarks":[],"parent_handle":"NET-104-0-0-0-0","cidr":"104.16.0.0/12","type":null,"events":[{"action":"last changed","timestamp":"2017-02-17T18:08:30-05:00","actor":null},{"action":"registration","timestamp":"2014-03-28T10:30:55-04:00","actor":null}]},"objects":{"CLOUD14":{"status":null,"roles":["registrant"],"handle":"CLOUD14","entities":["ABUSE2916-ARIN","ADMIN2521-ARIN","NOC11962-ARIN"],"links":["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CLOUD14","https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14"],"raw":null,"notices":null,"contact":{"kind":"org","name":"Cloudflare, Inc.","title":null,"phone":null,"role":null,"address":[{"type":null,"value":"101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}],"email":null},"events_actor":null,"remarks":[],"events":[{"action":"last changed","timestamp":"2017-02-17T18:19:16-05:00","actor":null},{"action":"registration","timestamp":"2010-07-09T13:10:42-04:00","actor":null}]},"ADMIN2521-ARIN":{"status":["validated"],"roles":["technical"],"handle":"ADMIN2521-ARIN","entities":null,"links":["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADMIN2521-ARIN","https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN"],"raw":null,"notices":null,"contact":{"kind":"group","name":"Admin","title":null,"phone":[{"type":["work","voice"],"value":"+1-650-319-8930"}],"role":null,"address":[{"type":null,"value":"101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}],"email":[{"type":null,"value":"rir@cloudflare.com"}]},"events_actor":null,"remarks":[],"events":[{"action":"last changed","timestamp":"2017-10-05T15:42:30-04:00","actor":null},{"action":"registration","timestamp":"2011-04-19T15:11:36-04:00","actor":null}]},"ABUSE2916-ARIN":{"status":["validated"],"roles":["abuse"],"handle":"ABUSE2916-ARIN","entities":null,"links":["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE2916-ARIN","https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN"],"raw":null,"notices":null,"contact":{"kind":"group","name":"Abuse","title":null,"phone":[{"type":["work","voice"],"value":"+1-650-319-8930"}],"role":null,"address":[{"type":null,"value":"101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}],"email":[{"type":null,"value":"abuse@cloudflare.com"}]},"events_actor":null,"remarks":[],"events":[{"action":"last changed","timestamp":"2017-02-17T18:11:38-05:00","actor":null},{"action":"registration","timestamp":"2011-02-14T19:00:47-05:00","actor":null}]},"NOC11962-ARIN":{"status":["validated"],"roles":["noc"],"handle":"NOC11962-ARIN","entities":null,"links":["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC11962-ARIN","https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN"],"raw":null,"notices":null,"contact":{"kind":"group","name":"NOC","title":null,"phone":[{"type":["work","voice"],"value":"+1-650-319-8930"}],"role":null,"address":[{"type":null,"value":"101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}],"email":[{"type":null,"value":"noc@cloudflare.com"}]},"events_actor":null,"remarks":[],"events":[{"action":"last changed","timestamp":"2017-02-17T18:15:44-05:00","actor":null},{"action":"registration","timestamp":"2011-04-19T15:25:31-04:00","actor":null}]}},"asn_country_code":"US","asn_date":"2014-03-28","asn_cidr":"104.24.112.0/20","nir":null,"query":"104.24.114.36","asn":"13335"}; 

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
console.log(res);
```